# iOS - Cannot use APNS certificate to create new provisioning profile

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, provisioning

I have create a new certificate that supports push notification service with an AppID that supports push notification. Now, when I create a new provisioning profile, I cannot find this certificate (only the old normal dev certificate). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you create the certificate via the website? If so, did you download it?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you properly, you did everything right. It's just a different certificates.
You need to use your 'old normal dev certificate' to sign provision, then use your APNS certificate to send push to your AppID.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a fresh certificate, you just need to remake your existing one with push enabled and then create a new provisioning profile from that cert. Also, if you are part of a team you will need authorize the newly created cert via the team manager. Check under the Pending certs to make sure it's not listed in there or check with your team manager.